Terraform update resource attribute conditionally else don't update (even to null)
Is there a way to change value of a resource attribute only if a condition is met, else do not assign a value at all, not even null?
something like this:
    resource "some_resource" "this" {     
       if var.flag == true:
          some_attribute = "some_value"      
       else:       
          pass  # do nothing, don't change its value to null 
    } 

I want to update the password only if the new_password variable is True.
if i use following, when new_password is false, the password gets set to null, which i am trying to avoid:
    resource "random_password" "myPassword" {
       length = 16     
    }     
    resource "snowflake_user" "myUser" {
       name  = var.name
       password = var.new_password ? resource.random_password.myPassword.result : null
   }

    resource "random_password" "myPassword" {
       count = var.new_password ? 1 : 0
       length = 16  
    } 
    resource "snowflake_user" "myUser" {
       name  = var.name
       password = var.new_password ? one(resource.random_password.myPassword[*].result) : null
    }


Are you trying to implement a password rotation mechanism?
You can control when the password changes using the random_password.keepers property - it's an arbitrary map of values that, when changed, will trigger the recreation of the resource.
You can regenerate the password based on 1 or more variables:
variable "password_version" {
  type        = string
  description = "Password version. Change this value to force a password change."
  default     = "v1"
}

resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"

  keepers = {
    // forces a password change when var.password_version changes
    version = var.password_version
  }
}

Or, as an alternative, use a more dynamic approach - for example, regenerate the password every year:
resource "time_static" "example" {}

resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"

  keepers = {
    # forces a password change when the current year changes
    year = time_static.example.year
  }
}

Full working example
Consider the following code:
variable "password_version" {
  type        = string
  description = "Password version. Change this value to force a password change."
  default     = "v1"
}

resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"

  keepers = {
    // forces a password change when var.password_version changes
    version = var.password_version
  }
}

output "snowflake_user" {
  value = nonsensitive(random_password.snowflake_user.result)
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_password.snowflake_user will be created
  + resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
      + bcrypt_hash      = (sensitive value)
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + keepers          = {
          + "version" = "v1"
        }
      + length           = 16
      + lower            = true
      + min_lower        = 0
      + min_numeric      = 0
      + min_special      = 0
      + min_upper        = 0
      + number           = true
      + numeric          = true
      + override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
      + result           = (sensitive value)
      + special          = true
      + upper            = true
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + snowflake_user = (known after apply)

Running terraform apply:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_password.snowflake_user will be created
  + resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
      + bcrypt_hash      = (sensitive value)
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + keepers          = {
          + "version" = "v1"
        }
      + length           = 16
      + lower            = true
      + min_lower        = 0
      + min_numeric      = 0
      + min_special      = 0
      + min_upper        = 0
      + number           = true
      + numeric          = true
      + override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
      + result           = (sensitive value)
      + special          = true
      + upper            = true
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + snowflake_user = (known after apply)
random_password.snowflake_user: Creating...
random_password.snowflake_user: Creation complete after 0s [id=none]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

snowflake_user = "hswjc&C_9_(9QM9>"

Running terraform plan again (no changes in variables):
random_password.snowflake_user: Refreshing state... [id=none]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Running terraform apply -var password_version=v2 (new value):
random_password.snowflake_user: Refreshing state... [id=none]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_password.snowflake_user must be replaced
-/+ resource "random_password" "snowflake_user" {
      ~ bcrypt_hash      = (sensitive value)
      ~ id               = "none" -> (known after apply)
      ~ keepers          = { # forces replacement
          ~ "version" = "v1" -> "v2"
        }
      ~ result           = (sensitive value)
        # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  ~ snowflake_user = "hswjc&C_9_(9QM9>" -> (known after apply)
random_password.snowflake_user: Destroying... [id=none]
random_password.snowflake_user: Destruction complete after 0s
random_password.snowflake_user: Creating...
random_password.snowflake_user: Creation complete after 0s [id=none]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.

Outputs:

snowflake_user = "<-czo}7lnIoxHzw0"

